# Newly created Google Task omits the supplied "TaskLink" property

Tags: google-apps-script, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I am trying to make a small Google Script that would automatically add Google Tasks to the "My List" `TaskList` after searching my GMail emails.

Everything goes fine except for adding a link to the email from which the `Task` is generated from. Trying to follow the API documentation doesn't really help.

This is the code for the actual task generator function:

```
function addTask(taskListId, myTitle, myEmailLink) {
  var task = Tasks.newTask(); // effectively same as "= {}".
  task.title = myTitle
  task.notes = 'blank';

  task.links = [{}]
  task.links[0].description = 'Link to corresponding email';
  task.links[0].type = 'email';
  task.links[0].link = 'myEmailLink';

  task = Tasks.Tasks.insert(task, taskListId);
}
```

Any ideas why the task I receive back has no `links`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Task->setLink work? (php api library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350321/how-does-task-setlink-work-php-api-library)

Comment: There is an open feature request on the Issue Tracker for `Task#links` to be writable: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68982867

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Per the Google Tasks API Documentation:](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks#resource-representations)

> `links[]`  *list*
>   Collection of links. This collection is read-only.

You cannot set these links by modifying a Task resource, i.e your code

```
task.links = [{}]
task.links[0].description = 'Link to corresponding email';
task.links[0].type = 'email';
task.links[0].link = 'myEmailLink';
```

is simply ignored by the server.

`TaskLinks` are, to my knowledge, unusable and non-configurable outside of the Googleplex. They may as well not exist to API users.

The only way I've been able to generate a `Task` that has one is by using the Gmail UI and selecting "Add to Tasks". The resulting task then includes this snippet in the last line of the Task item:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, according to the [Google Tasks API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks#resource-representations)  the links collection is unfortunately read-only.

As a potential work around, it appears you can add links to the notes section of a task, and the links are then directly clickable from the tasks pane in GMail.

[Picture: Task with clickable link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnXn8.png)

Your function can be modified to put the link in the notes section as follows:

```
function addTask(taskListId, myTitle, myEmailLink) {
  var task = Tasks.newTask(); // effectively same as "= {}".
  task.title = myTitle
  task.notes = 'link: ' + myEmailLink;

  task = Tasks.Tasks.insert(task, taskListId);
}
```

---

Combining this with the [getPermalink()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getpermalink) function on the `GmailApp` threads object allows for grabbing a deep link to the email you are looking for.

[Picture: Task with permalink to email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRoyf.png)

I'm working on a set of scripts that do some of the things you're talking about in addition to a few other things: https://github.com/tedsteinmann/gmailAutoUpdate

In my solution I have a function that grabs the GMail threads with a particular label (in my case @Task) and then creates a task setting the subject to `thread.getFirstMessageSubject()` and the notes to `thread.getPermalink()`

The entire function looks like this:

```
function processPending_() {

  var label_pending = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(LABEL_PENDING);
  var label_done = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(LABEL_DONE);

  // The threads currently assigned to the 'pending' label
  var threads = label_pending.getThreads();

  // Process each one in turn, assuming there's only a single
  // message in each thread
  for (var t in threads) {
    var thread = threads[t];

    // Grab the task data
    var taskTitle = thread.getFirstMessageSubject();
    var taskNote = 'Email: ' + thread.getPermalink();

    // Insert the task
    addTask_(taskTitle, taskNote, getTasklistId_(TASKLIST));

    // Set to 'done' by exchanging labels
    thread.removeLabel(label_pending);
    thread.addLabel(label_done);
  }

  // Increment the processed tasks count
  Logger.log('Processed %s tasks', threads.length);
}
```

Comment: Conveniently enough, the permalink goes directly to the thread which displays updated correspondence.